# VBA MACRO Stuck in a Loop

Tags: vba

I'm working in VBA in Reflections for IDX. I can get it to enter the loop but then it never leaves the loop.

```
While returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Reload Run ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
     If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
         While returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Load new Run for date ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
         Wend
     Else
         osCurrentScreen.SendKeys "N"
         osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return
     End If
Wend
```

It will enter the loop but gets stuck.

I have attempted to use `do loop`, `do while`, and `while wend`. I have changed the wording for the prompts, and have sometimes not entered the loop, have got stuck in the loop, or have skipped the loop altogether.

2nd try with a do loop - same result it will enter the loop but will not leave and move on to the next step

```
        Do

            If returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Reload Run ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes) Then
           osCurrentScreen.SendKeys "N"
           osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return

          Else
     'how do i add end loop here? end exit and wend do not work  
     End If

   Loop
```

i believe the issue is it's not actually reading the prompts and just skipping through doing whatever it wants.

attempt # 3 at the loop

```
  Do While returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Reload Run ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)

 'returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Reload Run ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
 If returnValue = ReturnCode_Success Then
    osCurrentScreen.SendKeys "N"
    osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return

'returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3("? N=> ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)

  '  Exit Do

   ' returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Load new Run for date ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
 Else
     osCurrentScreen.SendKeys "Y"
     osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return


    End If
Exit Do
 Loop
```

full code below

```
Sub Main()
        Const NEVER_TIME_OUT = 0
        Const DIALOG_TITLE = "idxlog"


        Dim filedata As String
        Dim row As Integer
        Dim singleFile As String
        Dim strdate As String
        strdate = Format(Date, "mmddyyyy")
        Dim osCurrentScreen As Screen
        Dim osCurrentTerminal As Terminal
        Dim returnValue As Integer

        Set osCurrentTerminal = ThisFrame.SelectedView.control
        Set osCurrentScreen = osCurrentTerminal.Screen

        NUL = Chr(0)
        LF = Chr(10)
        CR = Chr(13)
        ESC = Chr(27)

        singleFile = Dir$("C:\CHG" + strdate + ".DAT")
        If singleFile <> "" Then
        FileCopy "C:\CHG" + strdate + ".DAT", "C:\ CHG" + strdate + ".SAVE"
         End If






        If canceled Then Exit Sub


    With Application
        'log into TEST


'SELECT BAR
    'FOR TEST UNCOMMENT
    osCurrentScreen.SendKeys "1"
    'FOR LIVE UNCOMMENT
    'osCurrentScreen.SendKeys "3"
    osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return
    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Enter Group: ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If
'SELECT GROUP
    osCurrentScreen.SendKeys "3"
    osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return
    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Select Function: ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If
'Step 5
'SELECT SIU INTERFACES
    osCurrentScreen.SendKeys "36"
    osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return
    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Select Activity: ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If
'Step 6
'SELECT CHARGE TO TES INTERFACE ACTIVITIES
    osCurrentScreen.SendKeys "50"
    osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return
    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(BS & ESC & "[25;1H", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If
'Step 7
'TYPE L TO LOAD INTERFACE
    osCurrentScreen.SendKeys "L"
    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Charge Interface Run Date: ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If
'Step 8
'DATE T=TODAY
    osCurrentScreen.SendKeys "T"
    osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return



 'While returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Reload Run ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
 'While returnValue = Ture

 While returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Reload Run ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
 ' (returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3("? N=> ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes))
   '         returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Load new Run for date ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
            If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
               ' Exit Do
               While returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Load new Run for date ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
               Wend
         Else
           osCurrentScreen.SendKeys "N"
           osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return
     End If
   ' Loop

 Wend

' Wait (1)




'STEP 9
'LOAD NEW RUN
    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3("? N=> ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
    Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
   End If
    osCurrentScreen.SendKeys "Y"
    osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return



'Step 10
'SERIAL NUMBER
    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Serial Number: ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
   If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If
    osCurrentScreen.SendKeys strdate
    osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return
    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Description: ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If

'Description and Device Prompts
    osCurrentScreen.SendKeys "CONTEXT"
    osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return
    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Device: ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If
    osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return
    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3("   Right margin: ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If

    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3("=> ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If
    osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return
    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing



'Step 12 -15
'Set source file
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Enter RMS file source (CCA/CONTEXT): ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If
    osCurrentScreen.SendKeys "CONTEXT"
    osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return
    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
'Step 16
'Process runs
'Step 17
'Reflections will wait on Prompt "Do you Wish To Continue?"  (Y)es
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Do you wish to continue ? Y=> ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If
    osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return
    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Press <ENTER> to Continue: ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If
    osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return
    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3("r" & ESC & "[16;1H" & ESC & "[1C" & ESC & "[1;7m  ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If

    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3("  Selected    F", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If

    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3("Q-Quit    F", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If

    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3("-OK    <HELP>-Help    F", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If

    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3("-More Keys           " & ESC & "[0m" & ESC & "[78D" & ESC & "[25;1H", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If
'Step 20 Process Context file
'send "p" to process
    osCurrentScreen.SendKeys "P"
    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Charge Interface Date: ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If
'step 21
'send date
    osCurrentScreen.SendKeys strdate
    osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return
    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Process run ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If

    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(" ? N=> ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If
    osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return
    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Charge Interface Date: ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If
    osCurrentScreen.SendKeys "T"
    osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return
    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Process run ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If

    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(" ? N=> ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If
    osCurrentScreen.SendKeys "Y"
    osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return
    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
'Step 24
'Do you want to Queue this activity? (N)o
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Do you want to queue this activity? No=> ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If

    'might not need
    'osCurrentScreen.SendKeys "N"
    osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return
    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Device: ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If
'Step 25
'Set Dir to DList2 and File Name
    osCurrentScreen.SendKeys "IDXSTAFF:CONTEXT" + strdate + ".TXT"
    osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return
    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3("   Parameters: ""RWSN"" => ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If
'Process is complete from Step 25
    osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return

    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3("r" & ESC & "[16;1H" & ESC & "[1C" & ESC & "[1;7m  ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If

    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3("  Selected    F", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If

    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3("Q-Quit    F", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If

    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3("-OK    <HELP>-Help    F", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If

    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3("-More Keys           " & ESC & "[0m" & ESC & "[78D" & ESC & "[25;1H", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If

'EXIT DONE
' Press VtF7 (Perform the Vt F7 function).
    osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_F7
    osCurrentScreen.SendKeys "Q"
    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Select Activity: ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If

    osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return
    'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
    returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Select Function: ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
    If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
        Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
    End If

    osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return

    Exit Sub


  End With
     End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. to make the question more comprehensible, you may wish to fix the code indentation.

Comment: You apparently keep re-inserting the < > signs in your code. Please refrain from that. It makes the example unreadable.

Comment: What is the condition on which the loop should terminate?

Comment: when the prompt changes from Reload run to Load new run

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be an infinite loop no matter what (or it will never execute because `returnValue` starts off with the same value as the result of `WaitForString`, but we don't see any of the preceding code so I can't guess)

```
While returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Load new Run for date ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
Wend
```

There is no way to change the `returnValue` because the loop body is empty.

As for the outer loop `returnValue` is never set so it will never change.

I expect you are thinking that `returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Load new Run for date ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)` will set the value of `returnValue` but this is not the case. The Wend operator is expecting a boolean value so this line tests if those two are equal and returns true or false.  YOu need to set your `returnValue` in the body of the loop. Errors like this are why languages like C# use `==` for equality comparisons and `=` for assignment. VBA is not so fortunate.

Update:

```
'Check the initial value
returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Reload Run ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
While returnValue = "your string"
     If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
         'check if you're in the state you want to trigger the exit condition
         While returnValue = "Load new run"
             'get the new current state
             returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Load new Run for date ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
         Wend
     Else
         osCurrentScreen.SendKeys "N"
         osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey ControlKeyCode_Return
     End If
     'Check before looping again
     returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(LF & "Reload Run ", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
Wend
```

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/160d_VRlq9vLrin2WoPI22eqElRpYt-v_A7iviVKhe6A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @JStiner What is this link?

Comment: google doc of the full code. didnt know if it woudl be readble if i put the whole think in a comment... i can do that if the google doc is a bad idea?

Comment: It's best to post the full code in your question so everyone can see it. Not everyone is going to open up a google doc. You can edit the question.

Comment: @JStiner I updated with some comments. Does that make sense? When you are looping are you seeing the value of `returnValue` change? Are you stepping through using the debugger?

Comment: yes, i stepped through the code and saw the returnValue change. when i run the code i get to here Reload Run 35? N=> N <---- this is the loop, i need to to type N and hit enter every time the prompt Reload Run occurs, which it does Load new Run for date 20140522?N=> <----- this is the trigger to exit the loop and move to next command, which it doesnt